# Code for a function that just returns after an hour -interview question

Tags: algorithm, time

I saw this question online from an interview:

Suppose you have this code:

```
void myFunction(){
  int time = clcTime();
  while (clcTime()-time!=3600);  
}
```

When `clcTime()` is a method that returns the seconds that passed since 00:00 of today.

(1). Find what this code snippet does.
(2). Some QA tester said this code fails at specific case. What's that case and how can you solve that issue?
(3). Another QA tester that during the day this code worked fine, but when he got to sleep - something went wrong. What can possibly be the problem and how can you solve it?

My attempt:
For (1), I think this function just suppose to run in a loop for an hour.
For (3), I think the problem is when the `time` variable get its value when the current hour of the day is in the range `[23:00:00,23:59:59]`. And that's because on that case, the value of `time` will be in the range `[23*3600,23*3600 + 3599]` and `clcTime()` can't return a matching value in the range `[24*3600, 24*3600 + 3599]`. So in that case, we know that the condition 'clcTime()-time' will never get a value of 3600 and we will get an infinite loop.

My suggestion for solving it is replacing the `while` line with those lines:

```
int measure = clcTime() - time;
int measureModulo = measure % 3600;

while (measure==0 || measureModulo!=0){
    measure = clcTime() - time;
    measureModulo = measure % 3600;
}
```

The only problem I still have is that I can't figure out (2) - I don't find any other problem with this code.

Do you have any idea what else can be problematic with this code?
Also, please feel free to correct me if I was wrong with what I wrote for (1) and (3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another problem with this code, and your fix, is that it checks `clcTime()` for an *exactly matching* value.  If the system is busy and the loop doesn't get to run for more than a second, then it will miss the matching second and continue waiting for at least another hour.

Also there will be problems when the user changes the system clock or system time zone, when daylight savings time comes into or out of effect, when the clock is automatically adjusted for leap seconds, etc.

Comment: What you wrote with the exact matching seems like the case the interviewer looked on (2). But I wonder what can be a solution for that. The best thing I thought about is changing my fix solution so that we will add a variable to indicate when the `measureModulo` current value is smaller that its value in the former loop iteration and we will break the loop in this case. This will ensure the function will stop after a hour or maybe a few seconds later. I guess that there's allways a chance for a delay in any implementation so I wonder if you can do better than that?

Comment: Yes, like this: `elapsed = clcTime()-time;  if (elapsed<0) { elapsed += 86400; } if (elapsed >= 3600) break;`

Comment: Well, it's seem to me pretty much the same as the idea I suggested in my comment - but you wrote it in another way. Is there any advantage for what you wrote here when there's some delay in the system when we are close to `3600`?

Comment: It will break when `elapsed` is anywhere between 3600 and 86400 -- it has 23 hours to respond instead of just 1 second